# DataList repeates as count of Session that binded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, repeater, datalist

I am using **Session** to pass values that got from user in first page, to second page and list them. To list the data I use **DataList** but when I run it repeates multiple times and prints the same data for 17 times (**Data Count in Session**).

This is my (***.aspx**) file:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dgList" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row static-info">
            <div class="col-md-5 name"> Name: </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 value"><%#Session["gName"].ToString() %></div> 
            <%--<%G Adi %>--%>
        </div>                      
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And (***.cs**) file where I bind the **DataList** to **Session**:

```
if (Session["Kategori"].ToString().Equals("Dg"))
{
    dgList.DataSource = Session;
    dgList.DataBind();
    dgList.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: you are not binding data from session.

Comment: I couldn't understand.

Comment: in session what are you storing???